# Error in R - Unexpected '}' in " }"

Tags: r

I am getting the error:

`Error: Unexpected '}' in "   }`

I have put closing brackets for every open bracket, but am not sure why I am getting this error.

The error arises when I run the following code:

```
#find number of Columns & Rows

numcol <- ncol(training_main)  
numrow <- nrow(training_main)


attach(training_main)  
NA_count <- as.data.frame(sapply(training_main, function(x) sum(is.na(x))))  
for(i in 1:numcol)    
{  
     if (NA_count > 0)  
  {  
  for(j in 1:numrow)  
  {    
    if(is.na(training_main[j,i])    
      {   
         training_main[j,i] <- as.character(training_main[j,i])    
         training_main[j,i] <- "Empty"    
         training_main[j,i] <- as.factor(training_main[j,i])     
         print("empty printed")    

       }     
  }     
}    
}
```

Is the nested for -if - for - if as mentioned below allowed in R? That is the logic that I have to use. Is there any other way I can run this code?

Comment: You've had two hours to look at this and see how badly formatted it is. Please try and improve the formatting of your questions. There is a preview that shows you what it will look like. Learn a bit about marking up questions.

Comment: @Spacedman, I am sorry for this. Its my bad. Thanks for pointing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error is due to missing `')'` in the second `if` statement in your code.

```
if(is.na(training_main[j,i])
```

change to

```
if(is.na(training_main[j,i]))
```